# adding one pixel to table heigh change the style

Tags: html, css

I have a div `class = contentArea` that has two divs:

1. div `class = informationClass`
2. div `class = chartsClass`

under the `contenArea` div, I have div `class = agent-table-wrap`

the `informationClass` div has a table `class = informationTableClass`

that table has a height.

when I make the height 692. this is what I got

[image]

#### my problem

when I increase the height to `693`, I got a huge margin area at the left. this is it[image]

I hope if you can help me to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Define your** `.contentArea` `class`  `overflow:hidden;`

**as like this**

```
.contentArea{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

### --------------------------------------

2nd option is this

**define** a class `.clearfix` and apply to your `.contentArea` as like this

**css**

```
.clearfix{*zoom:1}

.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}

.clearfix:after{clear:both}
```

**html**

```
<div class="contentArea clearfix"> // define here class
```

Comment: the `.contentArea` has a `height` = 100%. do you mean to remove that too?

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left;` and `clear:both;` to your .agent-table-wrap class.